# XHTML w3c validation error "reference to non-existent ID "xxxxx""

Tags: xhtml, html, accessibility, w3c-validation

For this portion of code

```
<label for="gender">I am:</label>
<select class="select" name="sex" id="sex">
  <option value="0">Gender:</option>
  <option value="1">Female</option>
  <option value="2">Male</option>
</select>
```

W3C Validator giving this error **reference to non-existent ID "gender"**

How to solve this?

**Edit**

Getting here also

**reference to non-existent ID "birthday"**

```
<label for="birthday" class="birthday">Birthday:</label>

<div class="field_container"> 

<select name="birthday_month" id="birthday_month" class="">
<option value="-1">Month:</option>
<option value="1">Jan</option>
<option value="2">Feb</option>
<option value="3">Mar</option>
</select> 
<select id="birthday_day" name="birthday_day">
<option value="-1">Day:</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="birthday_year" name="birthday_year">
<option value="-1">Year:</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2009">2009</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>

</select>
</div>
```

Comment: The second example needs to be fixed the same way the first one has been corrected (by several answers): The `for` attribute of `<label>` elements needs to reference the `id` attribute of some other element. You have no `id` attribute that equals _"birthday"_. You need to set the `for` attribute to an id that exists somewhere in the document (like _"birthday_month"_ or _"birthday_year"_).

Comment: @elusive - but i have 3 different id for birthday

Comment: gear-solid: Then select one. You cannot use multiple IDs in the `for` attribute.

Comment: gear-solid see my updated answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the value of the `for` attribute in the `label` element:

```
<label for="sex">I am:</label>
```

**Edit to add:**

Your second example is more complicated, because you're using one label for three input fields.

I'd recommend something like the following:

Add the following CSS rule to your site:

```
.hidden_label {
  font-size:1px;
  height:0;
  line-height:0;
  margin:0 0 0 -1000px;
  text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

Then update your form:

```
<div class="birthday">Birthday:</div>

<div class="field_container"> 

<label for="birthday_month" class="hidden_label">Birthday Month</label>
<select name="birthday_month" id="birthday_month" class="">
  <option value="-1">Month:</option>
  <option value="1">Jan</option>
  <option value="2">Feb</option>
  <option value="3">Mar</option>
</select> 

<label for="birthday_day" class="hidden_label">Birthday Day</label>
<select id="birthday_day" name="birthday_day">
  [...]
</select>

<label for="birthday_year" class="hidden_label">Birthday Year</label>
<select id="birthday_year" name="birthday_year">
  [...]
</select>
```

You want to do two things:

Have a visually appealing form for your users, and then for those users that are using assistive technology, provide some additional helpers along the way. Using the CSS class I defined above, you are ensuring that screen readers will still see the elements and read their contents when the user moves into the form elements, while hiding all the additional labels from the visual site.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `id="gender"` or `name="gender"`. You are using sex. Either use sex or use gender. Keep it consistent.

Comment: Thanks, what to do in 2nd example?